# Three.JS проблема подключения библиотеки из-за CORS

Tags: javascript, three.js, cors

у меня при подключении библиотеки для загрузки gltf формата возникла проблема, в частности CORS, я бы хотел узнать как мне решить эту делему, или же заменить glftf каким-нибудь другим Loader-ом
[image]

Comment: [загрузите с cdn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825787/4496422) или напишите локальный, сервер, который будет отдавать библиотеки по http

Comment: В копилку: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally